# NHibernate.QueryException Message : duplicate association path

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I have this code:

```
if (pertinentDataExists) {        
    List<Entity> operatorList = new List<Operator>();
    List<Entity> newOperatorList = criteria.newOperatorList;
    foreach (Operator operator in operatorList)
    {
        operatorList.Add(operator);
    }
    queryCriteria.CreateCriteria("OperatorList").Add(Restrictions.In("Operator", operatorList));
}
```

and then later:

```
if (otherPertinentDataExists) {
    Object[] objects = new Object[criteria.newRoleTypeList.Count];                                                                                                                
    for (int  = 0; i < criteria.RoleTypeList.Count; i++) {                                                                                       
        objects[i] = criteria.RoleTypeList[i].Id;   
    }                                                                                       
    queryCriteria.CreateCriteria("OperatorList").Add(Restrictions.In("Role", objects));
}
```

These work separately just fine. However, if it is the case that both cases have criteria to add to the list, then I get:

> NHibernate.QueryException Message : duplicate association path:
>   OperatorList

How do I add restrictions for `Role` if the criteria is already created?

Comment: looks like you could check if it already exists with `GetCriteriaByPath("OperatorList")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two options. The first, if possible (being in the same method), create Criteria and reference them as a local variable:

```
var operatorListCriteria = queryCriteria.CreateCriteria("OperatorList");

if ( myCondition1 )
{
  operatorListCriteria.Add(...
}
if ( myCondition2 )
{
  operatorListCriteria.Add(...
}
```

The second, create criteria with "alias" and then, later, anywhere, you can find them with `GetCriteriaByAlias(aliasPath)`:

```
var aliasPath = "OperatorListAlias";
var operatorListCriteria = queryCriteria.CreateCriteria("OperatorList", aliasPath);
...
// later find them by aliasPath
var subCriteria = queryCriteria.GetCriteriaByAlias(aliasPath);
```

*NOTE: Also check the `GetCriteriaByPath(associationPath)`*

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "a Also check the GetCriteriaByPath(associationPath)" Do I have to check both aliasPath and assocationPath? or is checking only one of these necessary?

Comment: I was not so clear: I wanted to say, that you can also use `GetCriteriaByPath`, which is other way how to search for existing subcriteria. So you can use both of them (`GetCriteriaByAlias` or  `GetCriteriaByPath`) ... depends on which is better for you